# Having Troubles with trying to fix an error I'm receiving from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the PHP Code I have that is Causing this Error, I haven't had this error come up before and I searched and looked around before posting and Couldn't find a way to get ride of the error.

PHP (WORKING PHP) :

```
   <?php 
    require('includes/config.php'); 
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    if($_POST['username'] != $_SESSION['user']['username']) 
    { 
        // Define our query parameter values 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username']
        );

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username"); 
        $stmt->execute($query_params);

        // Retrieve results (if any) 
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) 
        { 
            die("This username is already in use"); 
        }

        try 
        { 
            $query_params = array( 
                ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                ':last_username' => $username
            );

            // Execute the query 
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET username = :username WHERE username = :last_username"); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 
          } 

?>
```

HTML:

```
                               <div id="changeusername" class="tab-pane">
                     <h3> Change Your Username : </h3>                  
  <form  method="post" action="changeusername.php" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="New Username" autofocus  value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Your Password">
                   <br>
                    <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" name="submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Change Username</button>


              </form>
```

Error I'm Receiving, after I input Boom2 Which is the New Username and boom1 is the oldd Username: 
**Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''boom2' WHERE username = 'boom1'' at line 1**

Comment: You need to specify what column you want to set new values for, like `SET username = :username`. But you should also bind the variable in your where clause

Comment: Getting a HTTP 500 Error on all of the answers

Comment: Then enable error reporting and check your logs. We don't magically know what's wrong, but PHP will tell you if you just let it ;-)

Comment: Haha Forgot all about that! Thanks!

Comment: Also it doesn't make sense to fetch on an update query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite your php code to error if username exists and correct your update query. Please try it:

```
<?php 
    require('includes/config.php'); 
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    if($_POST['username'] != $_SESSION['user']['username']) 
    { 
        // Define our query parameter values 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username']
        );

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username"); 
        $stmt->execute($query_params);

        // Retrieve results (if any) 
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) 
        { 
            die("This username is already in use"); 
        }

        try 
        { 
            $query_params = array( 
                ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                ':last_username' => $username
            );

            // Execute the query 
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET username = :username WHERE username = :last_username"); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

    } 

?>
```

Comment: That Did It! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET :username WHERE username = '$username'");
```

to

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET username=:username WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind column names, nor have you even specified what to set the value to.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET username = :username WHERE username = '$username'");
```

May be what you meant. If you really want to have a variable column, you will need to sanitise it using a whitelist or something in your PHP.

By the way, you shouldn't being placing `$username` straight into the string, that should also be done using the prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind column next line of the query.

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET :username WHERE username = '$username'"); 
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$result = $stmt->execute();

- you may get Notice Error: "Undefined variable: _SESSION" and 
  "Undefined index: user"
  **Solutions :**
  $username               = $_POST['username'];
  $_SESSION['username']  = $username;